# Iterate over vector efficently

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I want to iterate over a vector of an custom structure "Edge".
I have sorted the vector beforehand for the attribute weight.
Sometimes I want to stop iterating over the vector, calculate other stuff.
When I iterate over the vector again, I want to start at the last visited element.

Example with Integers:
Edge : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
Iterate: 0,1,2
Break out of function and calculate other stuff
Iterate: [3,4,5,6]

I thought about saving a vector::iterator.
It would be easier to change the pointer to the first element to
the wanted element instead but I didn't found anything for this

Thanks.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Be aware that vector iterators are particularly vulnerable to being invalidated if the vector is resized at all.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with the "duplicate marked" question.
This is great.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
     do_work(vec[i]);
     if(i == breakPoint) {
         do_calculations();
     }
}
```

Where `breakPoint` is an int indicating the index at which you want to stop. Unless, breaking the function is really important. Then you could use a static `i`, but that has the potential to give you more of a headache than I think it's worth